# NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest progress tracking

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsurlsession

Im using `NSURLSession` `dataTask` with `NSOoperationQueue` to download a file with multiple connections for faster speed. Creating operations from `NSURLSession` and passing them to `OperationQueue`. Now my struggle here is, as i see in apple docs, only `downloadTask` has progress tracking, is it even possible to track the bytes received using `NSURLSession` `dataTask` ?

Answer (score 3):

per Apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionTaskDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLSessionTaskDelegate/URLSession:task:didSendBodyData:totalBytesSent:totalBytesExpectedToSend: the delegate is

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
          task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
didSendBodyData:(int64_t)bytesSent
totalBytesSent:(int64_t)totalBytesSent
totalBytesExpectedToSend:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToSend
```

URLSession(_:dataTask:didReceiveData:) is not being called,
at least not on ios 9.0,
otherwise Stefan's answer applies

Comment: Thank you! helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Configure your `NSURLSession` to have a delegate that implements the `NSURLSessionDataDelegate` protocol.

In the delegate, implement the `URLSession(_:dataTask:didReceiveData:)` method, wich will be called when data comes in. Which is a good place to update for example a progress bar.

Comment: Thanks @StefanArentz, could you please explain more in depth on how do i have to create the delegate ? I know how to configure the NSURLSession to use a delegate, but im not sure how to create the delegate itself. thanks